# Developer console does not open when chrome is opened with disabled flags for ShadowDOMv0

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, polymer-1.0

My app is built using Polymer v1.x. As per [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-10-02-webcomponents-v0-deprecations.html) Polymer blog, Chrome is deprecating `ShadowDOMV0`, `CustomElementsV0` and `HTMLImports` in March 2019. To test the behavior of my app I have used "`--disable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0`" chrome flag as stated in the Polymer blog.

My app crashes with these flags but I am not able to open the developer console to check the error. Infact, even if you open any page in chrome with these flags, browser does not let open the developer console.

***Please note:*** I have experienced similar issue when I opened Chrome with
"`--disable-blink-features=CustomElementsV0`". However, with `HTMLImports` flag it works fine.

Does anyone experience similar issue? Or, does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: This issue still exists, I'm running Chrome 72 on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The devtools sure are broken with this flag, and it logs an error:

> ERROR:CONSOLE(3081)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: element.createShadowRoot is not a function", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (3081)

As a workaround, you can inspect it remotely: [Remote debugging with Chrome Developer Tools](https://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html).

1. Open Chrome to test your site in: `Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/asdfasdf --disable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --remote-debugging-port=9222`
2. In a different instance of Chrome, visit `chrome://inspect`, and your page should appear under “Remote Target #LOCALHOST”.

Comment: Thank You! Your workaround does work I am able to see the errors now but I am still unable to debug my code as after reloading it losts connection. Do you have any insight on this?